# Sobre "brevemente que seja"

Tags: gramática, uso-de-palavras, origem-histórica, uso-mais-comum

É formal o suficiente escrever "brevemente que seja"? Por exemplo:

> Definir o termo com precisão nos leva a discorrer --- brevemente que
>   seja --- sobre a teoria X.

O que significa esse "que seja"?  De onde vem essa expressão?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, não vejo qualquer problema com a frase.

*Brevemente que seja* expressa uma concessão, como *ainda que*, *embora*, *apesar de*, *mesmo que*, *conquanto*, etc. Portanto equivale a:

> Temos de discorrer, ainda que (seja/discorramos) brevemente.

O conjuntivo/subjuntivo é aqui usado com valor concessivo. Além de ocorrer com as conjunções já referidas (exceto *apesar de*), também ocorre com *por* (*por mais pequeno que seja*, *por incrível que pareça*), ou em construções com duplicação do verbo (*seja como for*).

Exemplos em que o conjuntivo aparece sozinho a expressar concessão são mais incomuns, mas podemos encontrá-las facilmente, como este exemplo no corpus CETEMPúblico, por exemplo:

> Será constitucional uma tal exigência de silêncio que não pondera, minimamente que seja, os interesses e valores em jogo?

Em termos de registo, este uso estará mais do lado formal ou literário.

Comment: A expressão poderia ser substituída por "ainda que brevemente".

Comment: O que eu achei quando vi a pergunta foi que esse *que seja* é o mesmo que em *por mais/muito [qualquer coisa] *que seja*** que tu referes.

Comment: @Jacinto sim, o significado é o mesmo, mas aqui não se pode usar _por_. Pode dizer-se _leva-nos a fazer uma digressão, por (mais) breve que seja_, ou seja, trocando o verbo por um nome e o advérbio por um adjetivo.

Comment: @Jacinto hmm e daí nao tenho a certeza. _temos de discorrer, por brevemente que discorramos_ não me parece assim tão mal.

Comment: Sim naturalmente temos nome+adjetivo ou verbo+adverbo. O que me lembrei é que se tirarmos o *por* à fórmula tradicional, não se perde grande coisa: *quis dar o meu contributo, modesto que seja*... Talvez o *por* só seja necessário com *mais: por mais modesto que seja*.

Answer (score 0):

Particularmente nunca vi essa maneira de expressar isso. Eu utilizaria

> ainda que brevemente ...

Mas não creio que seja inadequado. Só me parece incomum.